# What does topology RLS restrictions in a limited relationship model mean?

Tags: powerbi

Limited relationships: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-relationships-understand#limited-relationships

> Enforcing RLS has topology restrictions.

What does topology RLS restrictions mean?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is RLS has some limitations in DirectQuery mode.

In the note, `Enforcing RLS has topology restrictions`, topology is referring to the infrastructure that the model resides on.  i.e. the power bi service or self-hosted servers, in the case of DirectQuery.

Limited relationships are created in two cases:

1. With Many to Many relationships
2. and DirectQuery Mode

With RLS (Row Level Security), you can't use the `test as role` or `view as role` features in DirectQuery Mode when using SSO.

More about limited relationships:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/strong-and-weak-relationships-in-power-bi/

More about RLS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls#considerations-and-limitations